# Existence and uniqueness with Picard approximations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was looking on old annotations about ODE's. In the section about Picard's approximations and I saw a exercise that was not done. That was the fallowing

Prove the existence and uniqueness of the fallowing ODE:

$y'=\sin(y)$

$y(0) = y_{0}$

Doing Picard approximation will give:

$y_0(t)=y_0$

$y_{1}(t) =y_0 + \int_0^t \sin(y_{0}) ds = y_0 + \sin(y_0)t$

$y_{2}(t) =y_0 + \int_0^t \sin(y_0+\sin(y_0)t)ds$

Since I'm a little rust, is it any way to let it a little les ugly?

EDIT: Sinse $f(t,y)=\sin(t)$ and $ \partial f(t,y)/\partial y= \cos(y) $ are continuous on the real line is it enough to affirm that $y(t)$ has a solution?

Comment: You can use the fact that $\sin(x)$ is Lipschitz as the derivative is bounded above by $1$ to show there is an interval where the solution exists and is unique. But this approach won't tell you the actual interval itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $sin(y)$ is Lipschitz continuous with  respect to $y$, it follows by Picard's theorem that the solution exists and is unique to the above equation. Furthermore, all you need is one potential solution. That is provided to you by what you wrote in the edit, namely that the derivative is bounded, hence again by Picard's theorem the successive approximations you were constructing are going to converge uniformly to a function that will satisfy the equation.

Comment: The $y$'s are correct? It seems so ugly

Comment: See, they may be ugly as they be, but by Picard's theorem they are guaranteed to converge. Now you just want the existence of a solution, not the nature of the solution, in which case these integrals need not be evaluated, it is sufficient that they converge.